# Why fatherView use Clip to bounds and set Corner Radius, son view can not clip？

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Thanks for everyone who click.

Like title, I have a picture like this. [image]

So, My idea is set a father view and set the corner radius and drag a green son view, set the father view clip to bounds "true", I think it will be success, but not. Father view really have rounded corners but son view is rectangular and keep out the rounded corners like this :
[image]

and this is my parentView's Attribute inspector.
[image]

And when it is not useful, I use the UIBezierPath draw the corner radius like this :

```
    let path: UIBezierPath?
    switch style {
    case .All :
        path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: radiousView.bounds.size)
    case .TopRightAndBottomRight :
        path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: radiousView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.bottomRight,.topRight,.topLeft,.bottomLeft], cornerRadii: radiousView.bounds.size)
    }
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = radiousView.bounds
    maskLayer.path = path?.cgPath
    radiousView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

In first time,".TopRightAndBottomRight" including "[.topRight,.bottomRight]",but ".bottomRight" is not working.

so I try to test ".allCorners" and"[.topRight,.topLeft,.bottomRight,.bottomLeft]".

".allCorners" is done , but "[.topRight,.topLeft,.bottomRight,.bottomLeft]" 
just have "[.topRight,.topLeft]" two rounded corners.

What is the different between the  ".allCorners" and "[.topRight,.topLeft,.bottomRight,.bottomLeft]"?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: eh…… I set it in Nib and use the @IBInspectable , so I don't have code. I just set the fatherView cornerRadius and clip to bounds. sonView set auto layout leading、top、bottom equal to fatherView and height is 5.

Comment: Can post ur Attribute inspector of ur parent view.

Comment: That Attribute is belong to parent view or child view(image view)